# Persisting registry system to store closures

Tags: php, laravel, closures

I am developing a custom (inhouse) php framework ontop of Laravel and currently working on a feature that allows developers to create customizable actions. The framework enables the definition of actions with titles, associated closures, and specified modal views. Here is a basic example of defining an action:

```
(new Action)
    ->title('Edit')
    ->action(function() {
        // Perform an action
    })
    ->modal('test.blade.php');
```

My problem arises when dealing with forms within modals. Specifically, I need to ensure that when a user submits a form, the associated closure defined in the action parameter is executed. The process needs to be dynamic, with the aim to handle all forms through a single endpoint. This endpoint should dynamically execute the closure associated with the form submission.

To achieve this, I want to implement a ClosureRegistry class. This class stores closures using unique keys, which can be passed through the form. Upon form submission, the registry would retrieve and execute the appropriate closure based on the provided key.

This is what I currently have

```
 class ClosureRegistry
{
    private $closures = [];

    public function addClosure($id, Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->closures[$id] = $closure;
    }

    public function getClosure($id)
    {
        return $this->closures[$id] ?? null;
    }
}
```

However, the main challenge I am facing is persisting the ClosureRegistry across page loads. Since submitting a form triggers a page reload, I need a reliable method to maintain the state of the ClosureRegistry.

How can I persist the closureregistery between page loads?
Any advice or best practices in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you have a list of actions that are defined in the system? And when submitting a form through some of them, the closures function should be called?

Comment: you can have a look into how Laravel dispatches closure jobs.